# How to cache simple Flask Restful API

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, flask-caching

I am working on my first Flask Restful API and I'm trying to cache it for a week so that it only sends out a single request to update on Sundays. I am planning to upload it to Heroku on a Sunday so that the timeout (604800) I've set is synced to Sunday. I am able to create the page that displays JSON just fine but I am looking for some advice with the caching bit as I have a feeling that I am not doing it correctly and I'm not sure how to check it locally to see if it even works before uploading it to Heroku.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

class Products(Resource):
    @cache.cached(timeout=604800) # cache set to 1 week in seconds
    def get(self):
        product_list = []
        item_count = len(product)
        for x in range(item_count):
            product_list.append({'title':product[x].title, 'url':product[x].url,'image':product[x].images.medium})
        return {'product_list':product_list}


api.add_resource(Products, '/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, you can easily check if the caching is working by putting a time.sleep(60) into your route

if the caching doesnt work, it will wait 1 minute before sending a response every time - if everything is set up correctly, it will only do so once a week (because when caching is active, the line "sleep" will no longer be executed)

you can check this locally with Postman, or by simply visiting the url in your browser

-> remember to remove this obviously before going live!

here's a good video about it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iO0sL6Vyfps